Hollow shape produced by Geometry Nodes is filled-in when sliced in Creality Print

Here is a shape I made in blender by extruding a Bezier curve in its Data panel, and combining with a copy of the curve around which I swept a profile curve to create an edge:

It successfully slices in Creality Print as so:

I wanted to recreate basically the same shape but using Geometry Nodes. I succeeded

However, this new object gets completely filled-in when sliced:

Why is the empty space considered solid when produced by Geometry Nodes?

When you enable Face Orientation in the Overlays you can see that the face normals of the walls are incorrect with their inside pointing out (red color):

If you take a Flip Faces node and place it on the connection which puts the walls into the Join Geometry nodes, everything looks correct and you get a correct result in the slicer software:

By the way, the base ring of the other object has inverted normals as well, however since the base is a separate closed object I think (but don't quote me here, I'm no slicer software expert) the slicing software automatically switches the normals since it's no open mesh. But on the other version there are unconnected pieces (Join Geometry does not merge duplicate vertices with each other) and you have mixed orientations, some correct, some incorrect so this is probably making problems.

also consider adding a merge by distance node at the end of the node tree to merge the walls together, otherwise the slicer might only see open patches

@aliasguru Ultimaker Cura doesn't see a problem there, and for the closed top the inverted faces are the main problem (Merge by Distance without flipping the faces for example does not help). Also the base is unconneccted to the walls anyway and still is after merging by distance, so if that's no problem for printing I see no reason to add it here. But of course you can optionally do that.
